# AS2 Parse XML Problem

Tags: xml, parsing, actionscript-2

I have an xml file and a flash file. The flash file reads the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<banners>
    <banner>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <image>http://www.search-this.com/wp-content/themes/big-blue/images/company-logos1.gif</image>
        <link>http://google.com/</link>
    </banner>
</banners>
```

Now this works:

```
trace(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);
^ shows <title>Hello World</title>
```

But this shows NULL:

```
trace(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Why is it showing NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
trace(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
//--------------------------------------------------^ another childNodes
```

Reason: The text itself is a so-called text node. It is a child of the title element (an "element node").

Cheers,

Comment: By the way: The nodeValue of an element node is defined as, and hence ever and always, NULL.